# by checking the checkbox the checkbox text and jLabel icon should be displayed in jEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I have a `JCheckBox` with some text and a `JLabel` with an `ImageIcon`

Requirement is by checking the `JCheckBox`, the `JCheckBox` text and `JLabel` icon should be displayed in `JEditorPane`

I used

```
if (jCheckBox3.isSelected()) {
    s1 = jCheckBox3.getText() + jLabel1.getIcon() ;

    }
```

And

```
jEditorPane1.setText(s1);
```

output is

“checkbox text” file:/G:/myProject/build/classes/myproject/img.png

Instead of image I am getting image path

Comment: Please read how to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will give you a better chance of getting good help if you post one for us to test.

Comment: You can edit your question and add the screenshot there.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Before JCeckBox is checked]
[image: After you checked the JCeckBox]

This is an example how you could do it:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;


public class CheckBoxCheckingDisplayImagePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private JCheckBox checkBox;
    private JLabel label;
    private JEditorPane editorPane;
    private JPanel editorPanel;

    public CheckBoxCheckingDisplayImagePanel() {

        try {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
            this.add(panel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxthA.jpg")));
            label = new JLabel(icon, SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL);
            checkBox = new JCheckBox("Check me!");
            checkBox.addActionListener(this);
            panel.add(label);
            panel.add(checkBox);
            editorPane = new JEditorPane();
            this.add(editorPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CheckBoxCheckingDisplayImagePanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CheckBoxCheckingDisplayImagePanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource().equals(checkBox)) {
            editorPane.setContentType("text/html");
            editorPane.setText("<img src=\"https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxthA.jpg\">");
        }
    }


}
```

Patrick

Comment: Thank you very much for your response which is very help full
But the problem isn’t solved yet

I am developing in netbeans IDE 

I am unable to get the image in netbeans with the same method is there any way i could share a screen shot

Comment: yes i tried, with the example code i am loosing some text can i share a screen shot